# Tokbox / Opentok Session has reached its connection limit

Tags: opentok, tokbox, vonage

We have implemented a Tokbox/Opeontok application for live video stream which generally works great but we've had quite a few users unable to join a session and encountering an error message 'Session has reached its connection limit. Please try again in a few minutes.' This isn't part of our code and so not something we've set any trigger for. It seems odd as our system is only ever used for between one and three user connections for any session.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so what seems to have been the cause?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: This may help https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029413432-How-many-participants-are-supported-in-a-session- what might help as well is if there is a code snippet from your side so everyone could see how you've set it up. And any other information you can provide. The more information the better the answer will be

Comment: Hi Matt The code for that particular video chat is:

<div class="videochat">
 <div id="otEmbedContainer"style="width:100%;height:600px;background:black"></div>
 <script src="https://tokbox.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=1bfae1ad-0ad2-4191-ac5b-f51af565522e&room=6ixgj6cpua2zitgd"></script>
</div>